# Is there a way to batch load navigation properties in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, lazy-loading

I'm using EF Core 5, suppose I have the following database model (code first, pseudo code).

```
Company {
  string Name,
  int PrimaryAddressId,
  Address PrimaryAddress,
  Location[] Locations
}

Address {
  string City,
  string StreetAddress
}

Location {
  int CompanyId,
  int AddressId,
  Address Address
}
```

I would like to load a bunch of companies (let's say 50) from the database, including all their related data.

I'm aware that I have 2 options to load related data, however, both have some caveats.

- Using lazy loading proxies: This will result in the `N+1` queries issue, it will query the related data entity by entity, so at the end of the day a huge amount of queries will be sent to the server.
- Using eager loading with `Include`s: This will result in a huge single query with an anormous amount of joins, possibly fetching a lot of redundant data and most likely it will be quiet slow. Not to mention that I explicitly need to enumerate all the wanted paths with `Include`s which is quiet error-prone.

What I'm looking for is some tool/library, whatever, what could *batch load* related data for my entities, in a way similar to this kind of code:

```
var companies = context.Company.Take(50);
var companyIds = companies.Select(e => e.Id).ToHashSet();

var addressIds = companies.Select(e => e.PrimaryAddressId).ToHashSet();
var addressesById = context.Address.Where(e => addressIds.Contain(e.Id)).ToDictionary(e => e.Id);
companies.ForEach(e => e.PrimaryAddress = addressesById[e.PrimaryAddressId]);

var locationsByCompanyId = context.Location.Where(e => companyIds.Contains(e.CompanyId)).ToLookup(e => e.CompanyId);
companies.ForEach(e => e.Locations.AddRange(locationsByCompanyId[e.Id]));

...
```

This seems to me as a middle-of-the-road approach with a quiet good performance (queries will use the `IN` operator and most likely utilize indexes). Also, the code seems to be kind of *boilerplate* in the sense that one *should be able to* generalize/automate it somehow with some tooling, using the model metadata, foreign keys, etc.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you actually encountered a (performance) problem or are you trying to solve a hypothetical problem? Databases that slow down because of some joins should not exist anymore, especially with ridiculously low numbers as 50 queries.

Comment: Have you tried `Include + AsSplitQuery()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Using eager loading with `Includes`: This will result in a huge single query with an anormous amount of joins (1), possibly fetching a lot of redundant data and most likely it will be quiet slow (2). Not to mention that I explicitly need to enumerate all the wanted paths with Includes which is quiet error-prone.(3)

Ad (1): Define "enormous amount of joins". In my experience, most self-respecting relational databases can handle several factors more joins than human users, without slowing down perceptibly.

Ad (2): Don't optimize for things that might possibly happen. Measure it, and *if* it is slow, analyze *why* it is slow. This sounds like premature optimization, a known anti-pattern.

Ad (3): This seems like the kind of low-level data-layer code that needs writing once (with ample tests!) and *should* be low-maintenance afterwards.

So my suggestion would be to write it, (stress-)test it, and *if* there are performance problems, analyze them and look for specific solutions for actual problems.

If *the same* data is retrieved repeatedly, I would focus more on a form of caching to counter potential performance issues, for instance.

Comment: _"In my experience, most self-respecting relational databases can handle several factors more joins than human users, without slowing down perceptibly."_ - only if you have the right indexes set-up first, though...

Comment: @Dai, of course, that goes without saying. "A formula 1 car can drive over 300 km/h" "yeah, but only if you put wheels on it". FK's referencing PK's in other tables should never be a problem. (And I expect PK's to be indexed).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. "Enormous amount of joins" = 15+ includes in this case, some of them are collections and/or 2 or even 3 level deep in the real code. I had hands-on bad experiences with such queries against SQL Server, but you might be right, first I should have measured/tested it. But in general, I just miss this feature. For example the ages old DevExpress XPO has this "preload" feature almost from its beginning.